# Parental controls and dock modification

Tags: macos, dock, parental-controls

I have created a user for my roommate on my mac.  I gave her restricted access using Parental Controls.  However, now I am testing out this user, I notice "Prevent the Dock from being modified" under the Apps tab of Parental Controls is checked and grayed out.  I've been looking for a way to uncheck the box, but I think it might be an option that is fixed after you pick it when creating the user.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

I created a test user, using the default settings.  "Prevent the Dock from being modified" was unchecked, and I left it that way.  This was the only way I found to adjust that setting.

My original problem was not being able to create shortcuts on the desktop of the new user and I figured it was due to the dock settings.  I tried to adjust those and found that it was grayed out.

With my test user (created with default settings) I was able to create shortcuts on the desktop like normal.

I hope this helps if anyone has a similar problem.

I haven't tested out this test user much, but I did notice that the new user with "Prevent the Dock from being modified" checked and grayed out had alot of bugs in it.  I might not use that user at all because of this.